# Nuget Update Packages.config in MSBuild BeforeBuild Step

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

I have been trying to write an MsBuild task to automatically get Nuget packages from a feed url and automatically update the packages.config to update to the latest version.

```
 // ---- Download and install a package at a desired path ----
  var sourceUri = new Uri("FEED URL");

  // ---- Update the ‘packages.config’ file ----
  var packageReferenceFile = new PackageReferenceFile("../../packages.config");
  string packagesPath = "../../packages";
  IPackageRepository sourceRepository = PackageRepositoryFactory.Default.CreateRepository(sourceUri.ToString());
  PackageManager packageManager = new PackageManager(sourceRepository, packagesPath);

  foreach (var sourcePackage in sourceRepository.GetPackages().Where(x => x.IsLatestVersion))
  {
    if (!packageReferenceFile.EntryExists(sourcePackage.Id + " " + sourcePackage.Version, sourcePackage.Version))
    {
      var oldPackage = packageReferenceFile.GetPackageReferences().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id.Contains(sourcePackage.Id));

      if (oldPackage != null)
      {
        packageReferenceFile.DeleteEntry(oldPackage.Id, oldPackage.Version);
      }

      packageManager.InstallPackage(sourcePackage.Id, SemanticVersion.Parse(sourcePackage.Version.ToFullString()));

      // Get the target framework of the current project to add --> targetframework="net452" attribute in the package.config file
      var currentTargetFw = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
        .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TargetFrameworkAttribute), false);
      var targetFrameworkAttribute = ((TargetFrameworkAttribute[]) currentTargetFw).FirstOrDefault();

      // Update the packages.config file    
      packageReferenceFile.AddEntry(sourcePackage.GetFullName(),
        SemanticVersion.Parse(sourcePackage.Version.ToFullString()), false,
        new FrameworkName(targetFrameworkAttribute.FrameworkName));
    }
  }
```

This is working fine as a console app and is automatically reading the file correctly and updating the necessary references.

When i try to run this as an MsBuild task I keep running into errors.

- An error has occurred during compilation. c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\dkkg20ya.0.cs(22,11) : error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'NuGet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
- The task factory "CodeTaskFactory" could not be loaded from the assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v15.0.dll". The task factory must return a value for the "TaskType" property.

This is the code I have put in the csproj (also moved to the nuget.targets to test)

```
<Target Name="BeforeBeforeBuild" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <UpdateNugetFiles />
  </Target>
<UsingTask TaskName="UpdateNugetFiles" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v$(MSBuildToolsVersion).dll" > 
    <Task>
        <Reference Include="System.Core" />
        <Using Namespace="System" />
        <Using Namespace="System.Linq" />
        <Using Namespace="System.Reflection" />
        <Using Namespace="System.Runtime.Versioning" />
        <Using Namespace="NuGet" />
        <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
            <![CDATA[
            try {
                // ---- Download and install a package at a desired path ----
  var sourceUri = new Uri("FEED URL");

  // ---- Update the ‘packages.config’ file ----
  var packageReferenceFile = new PackageReferenceFile("../../packages.config");
  string packagesPath = "../../packages";
  IPackageRepository sourceRepository = PackageRepositoryFactory.Default.CreateRepository(sourceUri.ToString());
  PackageManager packageManager = new PackageManager(sourceRepository, packagesPath);

  foreach (var sourcePackage in sourceRepository.GetPackages().Where(x => x.IsLatestVersion))
  {
    if (!packageReferenceFile.EntryExists(sourcePackage.Id + " " + sourcePackage.Version, sourcePackage.Version))
    {
      var oldPackage = packageReferenceFile.GetPackageReferences().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id.Contains(sourcePackage.Id));

      if (oldPackage != null)
      {
        packageReferenceFile.DeleteEntry(oldPackage.Id, oldPackage.Version);
      }

      packageManager.InstallPackage(sourcePackage.Id, SemanticVersion.Parse(sourcePackage.Version.ToFullString()));

      // Get the target framework of the current project to add targetframework="net452" attribute in the package.config file
      currentTargetFw = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
        .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TargetFrameworkAttribute), false);
      var targetFrameworkAttribute = ((TargetFrameworkAttribute[]) currentTargetFw).FirstOrDefault();

      // Update the packages.config file    
      packageReferenceFile.AddEntry(sourcePackage.GetFullName(),
        SemanticVersion.Parse(sourcePackage.Version.ToFullString()), false,
        new FrameworkName(targetFrameworkAttribute.FrameworkName));
    }
  }

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.LogErrorFromException(ex);
                return false;
            }
        ]]>
        </Code>
    </Task>
</UsingTask>
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this as cannot seem to find a solution.
Overall what to run this a pre step on a CI build to keep nugets up to date.

Thanks
Tim

Comment: If this is a class library, you should really [upgrade to the new `.csproj` format](https://www.natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/03/09/vs2015-to-vs2017-upgrade/), which gets rid of the old `.nuspec` and `packages.config` garbage. If not, read [The right way to restore NuGet packages](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2014/01/the-right-way-to-restore-nuget-packages.html). Either way, this is built-in functionality of MSBuild and you are reinventing the wheel with your build task.

Comment: This is a web project and we already have a csproj in the sln.  I know that MsBuild can automatically restore packages.  What i need to to automatically update the packages to the latest version that is available on the nuget feed

Comment: Yikes! That sounds like a recipe for instability.

Answer (score 1):

Just call

```
nuget restore "your_solution.sln"
```

Don't reinvent the wheel by writing it in C# code.

Comment: And don't forget to add your nuget.config file to specify where the feed is.

Answer (score 0):

> Nuget Update Packages.config in MSBuild BeforeBuild Step

Not sure where your code issue comes from. It may be simpler just use `NuGet.exe` to restore and update the solution instead of trying to use C# code.

So you could add following nuget command line in the MSBuild BeforeBuild Step

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBeforeBuild" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec Command="$(YourNuGetPath)\nuget.exe restore &quot;$(YouSolutionPath)\YourSolution.sln&quot; -PackagesDirectory &quot;$(YouPackagePath)\packages&quot;" />
    <Exec Command="$(YourNuGetPath)\nuget.exe update &quot;$(YouSolutionPath)\YourSolution.sln&quot;" />
  </Target>
```

Note: If you are using Visual Studio, Visual Studio will automatically check the missing packages during the build and restore them: [Package Restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore).

Hope this helps.